# Make <a> link fill full height of <div>

Tags: html, css

I have a header with links for navigation. Each link is a `div`, and inside it there is an `a` link. I want to make each a link fill the vertical and horizontal space of the div.

```css
.TopNav {
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.TopNav-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: gold;
}

.TopNav-item {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table-cell;
  margin-right: 20px;
  border: 1px solid tomato;
  height: 72px;
}
.TopNav-a {
  background-color: tomato;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<nav class="TopNav">
  <div class="TopNav-wrapper">
    <div class="TopNav-item">
      <a class="TopNav-a" href="">First</a>
    </div>
    <div class="TopNav-item">
      <a class="TopNav-a " href="">Second</a>
    </div>
    <div class="TopNav-item">
      <a class="TopNav-a" href="">Third</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

And a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6rp1canq/

Is this possible?

Comment: What do you mean "fill the vertical and horizontal space of the div"?  Do you mean you want the entire div to be clickable, or do you mean you want the link text to be larger?

Comment: Its better to use <li> instead of <div> for each menu -item

Answer (score 0):

Change `.TopNav-a` style in this way:

```
.TopNav-a {
  display: block;
  background-color: tomato;
  color: white;
  height: 72px;
  line-height: 72px;
}
```

Comment: Hm, I like percentages, and I can use `heigth: 100%`, but is there a way to avoid the `line-height: 72px` to vertical center the text?

Answer (score 0):

Write the `a` tag around the `div` doing `<a><div>Test</div></a>`

Answer (score 0):

You could use flexbox layout:

```css
.TopNav {
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.TopNav-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: gold;
}

.TopNav-item {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table-cell;
  margin-right: 20px;
  border: 1px solid tomato;
  height: 72px;
}
.TopNav-a {
  background-color: tomato;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<nav class="TopNav">
  <div class="TopNav-wrapper">
    <div class="TopNav-item">
      <a class="TopNav-a" href="">First</a>
    </div>
    <div class="TopNav-item">
      <a class="TopNav-a " href="">Second</a>
    </div>
    <div class="TopNav-item">
      <a class="TopNav-a" href="">Third</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: I could, but the side effects would be funny depending on the browser… Maybe not here, but I try to avoid flexbox as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You could just wrap the div in an anchor.